# PHP - Parsing XML Challenge

Tags: php, xpath, xml-parsing, simplexml, xml-attribute

I'm trying to parse a feed similar to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xml:base="https://api4.mysite.com/api/" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">Customers</title>
  <id>https://api4.mysite.com/api/Customers/</id>
  <updated>2017-07-27T08:00:15Z</updated>
  <link rel="self" title="Customers" href="Customers" />
  <entry>
    <id>https://api4.mysite.com/api/Contacts('00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201')</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2017-07-27T08:00:15Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="Contact" href="Contacts('00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201')" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ContactType" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="ContactType" href="Contacts('00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201')/ContactType" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ContactPhone" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="ContactPhone" href="Contacts('00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201')/ContactPhone" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Job" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Job" href="Contacts('00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201')/Job" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Inquiry" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Inquiry" href="Contacts('00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201')/Inquiry" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Address" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Address" href="Contacts('00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201')/Address" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/AdditionalContact" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="AdditionalContact" href="Contacts('00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201')/AdditionalContact" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Company" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Company" href="Contacts('00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201')/Company" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/CustomField" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="CustomField" href="Contacts('00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201')/CustomField" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Activity" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Activity" href="Contacts('00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201')/Activity" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/FutureInterest" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="FutureInterest" href="Contacts('00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201')/FutureInterest" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Note" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Note" href="Contacts('00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201')/Note" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/C800ResponseLead" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="C800ResponseLead" href="Contacts('00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201')/C800ResponseLead" />
    <category term="MSharpModel.Contact" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:id>00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201</d:id>
        <d:companyId>2199</d:companyId>
        <d:firstName>Shannon</d:firstName>
        <d:lastName>Hall</d:lastName>
        <d:middleInitial m:null="true" />
        <d:title m:null="true" />
        <d:incomeCode m:null="true" />
        <d:ageCode m:null="true" />
        <d:structureAgeCode m:null="true" />
        <d:reference m:null="true" />
        <d:businessName m:null="true" />
        <d:contactPhoneId>1d32d3ad-c710-4963-a425-eb7853c4fdf9</d:contactPhoneId>
        <d:primaryAddressId>b8a78bb8-3895-492f-a4a2-f6e287081dcf</d:primaryAddressId>
        <d:website1 m:null="true" />
        <d:website2 m:null="true" />
        <d:website3 m:null="true" />
        <d:email1 m:null="true" />
        <d:isActive m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:isActive>
        <d:lastUpdate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2015-05-15T14:49:45.143-04:00</d:lastUpdate>
        <d:createdDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2015-05-15T14:49:45.143-04:00</d:createdDate>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>https://api4.mysite.com/api/Contacts('992ABCSA-1231-8381-JKL8-38KDLALNA881')</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2017-07-27T08:00:15Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="Contact" href="Contacts('992ABCSA-1231-8381-JKL8-38KDLALNA881')" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ContactType" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="ContactType" href="Contacts('992ABCSA-1231-8381-JKL8-38KDLALNA881')/ContactType" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ContactPhone" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="ContactPhone" href="Contacts('992ABCSA-1231-8381-JKL8-38KDLALNA881')/ContactPhone" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Job" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Job" href="Contacts('992ABCSA-1231-8381-JKL8-38KDLALNA881')/Job" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Inquiry" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Inquiry" href="Contacts('992ABCSA-1231-8381-JKL8-38KDLALNA881')/Inquiry" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Address" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Address" href="Contacts('992ABCSA-1231-8381-JKL8-38KDLALNA881')/Address" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/AdditionalContact" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="AdditionalContact"  ▶
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Company" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Company" href="Contacts('992ABCSA-1231-8381-JKL8-38KDLALNA881')/Company" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/CustomField" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="CustomField" href="Contacts('992ABCSA-1231-8381-JKL8-38KDLALNA881')/CustomField" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Activity" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Activity" href="Contacts('992ABCSA-1231-8381-JKL8-38KDLALNA881')/Activity" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/FutureInterest" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="FutureInterest" href="Contacts('992ABCSA-1231-8381-JKL8-38KDLALNA881')/FutureInterest" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Note" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Note" href="Contacts('992ABCSA-1231-8381-JKL8-38KDLALNA881')/Note" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/C800ResponseLead" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="C800ResponseLead" href="Contacts('992ABCSA-1231-8381-JKL8-38KDLALNA881')/C800ResponseLead" />
    <category term="MSharpModel.Contact" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:id>992ABCSA-1231-8381-JKL8-38KDLALNA881</d:id>
        <d:companyId>2100</d:companyId>
        <d:firstName>Jane</d:firstName>
        <d:lastName>Fonda</d:lastName>
        <d:middleInitial m:null="true" />
        <d:title>Mrs.</d:title>
        <d:incomeCode m:null="true" />
        <d:ageCode m:null="true" />
        <d:structureAgeCode m:null="true" />
        <d:reference m:null="true" />
        <d:businessName m:null="true" />
        <d:contactPhoneId>427C367B-F490-412A-B9B0-ABABABABABAB</d:contactPhoneId>
        <d:primaryAddressId>f7668325-ba95-4bde-b28d-0226bbd4d9c7</d:primaryAddressId>
        <d:website1 m:null="true" />
        <d:website2 m:null="true" />
        <d:website3 m:null="true" />
        <d:email1 m:null="true" />
        <d:email1CanMail m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:email1CanMail>
        <d:email2 m:null="true" />
        <d:email2CanMail m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:email2CanMail>
        <d:email3 m:null="true" />
        <d:email3CanMail m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:email3CanMail>
        <d:isTagged m:type="Edm.Boolean" m:null="true" />
        <d:structureValueCode m:null="true" />
        <d:doNotMail m:type="Edm.Boolean" m:null="true" />
        <d:yearHomeBuilt m:null="true" />
        <d:maritalStatus m:null="true" />
        <d:lengthOfResidence m:null="true" />
        <d:styleOfHome m:null="true" />
        <d:mailMergeName>Jesse Peters</d:mailMergeName>
        <d:source>Access - KGuard</d:source>
        <d:creationDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2015-05-15T14:49:27.06-04:00</d:creationDate>
        <d:qbSyncDate m:type="Edm.DateTime" m:null="true" />
        <d:qbId m:null="true" />
        <d:isActive m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:isActive>
        <d:lastUpdate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2015-05-15T14:49:27.06-04:00</d:lastUpdate>
        <d:hasDNCPhone m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:hasDNCPhone>
        <d:hasDNEEmail m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:hasDNEEmail>
        <d:qbEditSequence m:null="true" />
        <d:qbSyncData m:type="Edm.Boolean" m:null="true" />
        <d:qbName m:null="true" />
        <d:createdDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2015-05-15T14:49:27.06-04:00</d:createdDate>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

but I'm having issues grabbing the namespaced sub- < entry > tags. It went fine when I only got back 1, but now that I'm pulling in multiple I'm really struggling to get a good array of objects.

Unfortunately, I've written so many different forms of my function, I'm not even sure which one comes closest now.

Example 1:

```
public function parseMultipleEntriesIntoAnObject($xml) {
        $z = new XMLReader();
        $z->xml($xml);
        //while ($z->read() && $z->name !== 'entry');
        // <content>
        // m:properties
        // d:<property_name
        $results = [];
        $key = "";
        while( $z->read() ) {
            //print($z->name);
            if ($z->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $z->name === 'entry') {
                $r = new \stdClass;
                //dd("Yeup");
                while ($z->read()) {
                    // reached the </entry>. skip to next                   
                    if ($z->nodeType === XMLReader::END_ELEMENT && $z->name === 'entry') {
                        $results[] = $r;
                        $z->next('entry');
                        $r = new \stdClass;
                    }
                    // this may mess up on nested elements. Oh well.
                    if ($z->nodeType === XMLReader::ELEMENT) {
                        $key = $z->name;
                    }
                    if ($z->nodeType === XMLReader::TEXT) {
                        //echo "$key = $z->value <br/>";
                        $r->{$key} = $z->value;
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
        $z->close();

        return $results;
    }
```

Examples 2 & 3:

```
private function getXMLEntries($xml) {
        $resultsArray = [];
        $str = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $xml));
        $z = new XMLreader;
        $doc = new \DOMDocument;

        $z->xml($str);
        $props = [];
        while ($z->read() && $z->name !== 'entry');
        while ($z->name === 'entry') {
            $x = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($z->expand(), true));
            var_dump($x->content);
            $resultsArray[] = $x;
            //$resultsArray[] = $z->expand();
            $z->next('entry');
        }
        return $resultsArray;
    }
    private function processXMLProperties($xml) {
        $str = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', $xml));
        $z = new XMLreader;
        $z->xml($str);
        $props = [];
        while ($z->read() && $z->name !== 'm:properties');
        $key = "";
        while ($z->read()) {
            if ($z->nodeType === XMLReader::ELEMENT) {
                $key = $z->name;
                $z->read();
            }
            if ($z->nodeType === XMLReader::TEXT) {
                $props[$key] = $z->value;
            }
        } return $props; }
```

Hopefully you can see what I'm trying to do. If it matters, this comes in via a Stream using Guzzle. Basically I need an array of objects, where each object contains the various properties of < m:properties >, ideally without their d: prefix.

Note that based on what I append to my query, any of the relevant < link ... sections could have data.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Xpath.

The `d` namespace isn't defined in the XML string but when adding `xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"` to the `<feed>` tag, the following works:

```
<?php

$str = <<<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xml:base="https://api4.mysite.com/api/"  xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">Customers</title>
  <id>https://api4.mysite.com/api/Customers/</id>
  <updated>2017-07-27T08:00:15Z</updated>
  <link rel="self" title="Customers" href="Customers" />
  <entry>
    <id>https://api4.mysite.com/api/Contacts('00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201')</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2017-07-27T08:00:15Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="Contact" href="Contacts('00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201')" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ContactType" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="ContactType" href="Contacts('00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201')/ContactType" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ContactPhone" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="ContactPhone" href="Contacts('00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201')/ContactPhone" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Job" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Job" href="Contacts('00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201')/Job" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Inquiry" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Inquiry" href="Contacts('00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201')/Inquiry" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Address" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Address" href="Contacts('00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201')/Address" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/AdditionalContact" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="AdditionalContact" href="Contacts('00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201')/AdditionalContact" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Company" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Company" href="Contacts('00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201')/Company" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/CustomField" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="CustomField" href="Contacts('00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201')/CustomField" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Activity" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Activity" href="Contacts('00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201')/Activity" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/FutureInterest" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="FutureInterest" href="Contacts('00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201')/FutureInterest" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Note" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Note" href="Contacts('00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201')/Note" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/C800ResponseLead" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="C800ResponseLead" href="Contacts('00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201')/C800ResponseLead" />
    <category term="MSharpModel.Contact" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:id>00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201</d:id>
        <d:companyId>2199</d:companyId>
        <d:firstName>Shannon</d:firstName>
        <d:lastName>Hall</d:lastName>
        <d:middleInitial m:null="true" />
        <d:title m:null="true" />
        <d:incomeCode m:null="true" />
        <d:ageCode m:null="true" />
        <d:structureAgeCode m:null="true" />
        <d:reference m:null="true" />
        <d:businessName m:null="true" />
        <d:contactPhoneId>1d32d3ad-c710-4963-a425-eb7853c4fdf9</d:contactPhoneId>
        <d:primaryAddressId>b8a78bb8-3895-492f-a4a2-f6e287081dcf</d:primaryAddressId>
        <d:website1 m:null="true" />
        <d:website2 m:null="true" />
        <d:website3 m:null="true" />
        <d:email1 m:null="true" />
        <d:isActive m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:isActive>
        <d:lastUpdate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2015-05-15T14:49:45.143-04:00</d:lastUpdate>
        <d:createdDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2015-05-15T14:49:45.143-04:00</d:createdDate>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>https://api4.mysite.com/api/Contacts('992ABCSA-1231-8381-JKL8-38KDLALNA881')</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2017-07-27T08:00:15Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="Contact" href="Contacts('992ABCSA-1231-8381-JKL8-38KDLALNA881')" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ContactType" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="ContactType" href="Contacts('992ABCSA-1231-8381-JKL8-38KDLALNA881')/ContactType" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/ContactPhone" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="ContactPhone" href="Contacts('992ABCSA-1231-8381-JKL8-38KDLALNA881')/ContactPhone" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Job" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Job" href="Contacts('992ABCSA-1231-8381-JKL8-38KDLALNA881')/Job" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Inquiry" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Inquiry" href="Contacts('992ABCSA-1231-8381-JKL8-38KDLALNA881')/Inquiry" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Address" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Address" href="Contacts('992ABCSA-1231-8381-JKL8-38KDLALNA881')/Address" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/AdditionalContact" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="AdditionalContact"  />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Company" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Company" href="Contacts('992ABCSA-1231-8381-JKL8-38KDLALNA881')/Company" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/CustomField" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="CustomField" href="Contacts('992ABCSA-1231-8381-JKL8-38KDLALNA881')/CustomField" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Activity" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Activity" href="Contacts('992ABCSA-1231-8381-JKL8-38KDLALNA881')/Activity" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/FutureInterest" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="FutureInterest" href="Contacts('992ABCSA-1231-8381-JKL8-38KDLALNA881')/FutureInterest" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Note" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="Note" href="Contacts('992ABCSA-1231-8381-JKL8-38KDLALNA881')/Note" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/C800ResponseLead" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" title="C800ResponseLead" href="Contacts('992ABCSA-1231-8381-JKL8-38KDLALNA881')/C800ResponseLead" />
    <category term="MSharpModel.Contact" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:id>992ABCSA-1231-8381-JKL8-38KDLALNA881</d:id>
        <d:companyId>2100</d:companyId>
        <d:firstName>Jane</d:firstName>
        <d:lastName>Fonda</d:lastName>
        <d:middleInitial m:null="true" />
        <d:title>Mrs.</d:title>
        <d:incomeCode m:null="true" />
        <d:ageCode m:null="true" />
        <d:structureAgeCode m:null="true" />
        <d:reference m:null="true" />
        <d:businessName m:null="true" />
        <d:contactPhoneId>427C367B-F490-412A-B9B0-ABABABABABAB</d:contactPhoneId>
        <d:primaryAddressId>f7668325-ba95-4bde-b28d-0226bbd4d9c7</d:primaryAddressId>
        <d:website1 m:null="true" />
        <d:website2 m:null="true" />
        <d:website3 m:null="true" />
        <d:email1 m:null="true" />
        <d:email1CanMail m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:email1CanMail>
        <d:email2 m:null="true" />
        <d:email2CanMail m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:email2CanMail>
        <d:email3 m:null="true" />
        <d:email3CanMail m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:email3CanMail>
        <d:isTagged m:type="Edm.Boolean" m:null="true" />
        <d:structureValueCode m:null="true" />
        <d:doNotMail m:type="Edm.Boolean" m:null="true" />
        <d:yearHomeBuilt m:null="true" />
        <d:maritalStatus m:null="true" />
        <d:lengthOfResidence m:null="true" />
        <d:styleOfHome m:null="true" />
        <d:mailMergeName>Jesse Peters</d:mailMergeName>
        <d:source>Access - KGuard</d:source>
        <d:creationDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2015-05-15T14:49:27.06-04:00</d:creationDate>
        <d:qbSyncDate m:type="Edm.DateTime" m:null="true" />
        <d:qbId m:null="true" />
        <d:isActive m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:isActive>
        <d:lastUpdate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2015-05-15T14:49:27.06-04:00</d:lastUpdate>
        <d:hasDNCPhone m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:hasDNCPhone>
        <d:hasDNEEmail m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:hasDNEEmail>
        <d:qbEditSequence m:null="true" />
        <d:qbSyncData m:type="Edm.Boolean" m:null="true" />
        <d:qbName m:null="true" />
        <d:createdDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2015-05-15T14:49:27.06-04:00</d:createdDate>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
</feed>
EOF;


$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

$xml->registerXPathNamespace( 'd', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata' );
$xpath = $xml->xpath( '//m:properties/d:*' );

foreach($xpath as $key => $node)
{
    echo $node->getName() . ' = ' . (string)$node . "\n";

    $subx = $node->xpath('@*');

    foreach($subx as $subnode) {
        echo "\t" . $subnode->getName() . ' = ' . (string)$subnode . "\n";
    }

    echo "-------------------------------------------------------\n";
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
id = 00000001-A000-0000-1000-030102101201
-------------------------------------------------------
companyId = 2199
-------------------------------------------------------
firstName = Shannon
-------------------------------------------------------
lastName = Hall
-------------------------------------------------------
middleInitial = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
title = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
incomeCode = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
ageCode = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
structureAgeCode = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
reference = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
businessName = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
contactPhoneId = 1d32d3ad-c710-4963-a425-eb7853c4fdf9
-------------------------------------------------------
primaryAddressId = b8a78bb8-3895-492f-a4a2-f6e287081dcf
-------------------------------------------------------
website1 = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
website2 = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
website3 = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
email1 = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
isActive = true
        type = Edm.Boolean
-------------------------------------------------------
lastUpdate = 2015-05-15T14:49:45.143-04:00
        type = Edm.DateTime
-------------------------------------------------------
createdDate = 2015-05-15T14:49:45.143-04:00
        type = Edm.DateTime
-------------------------------------------------------
id = 992ABCSA-1231-8381-JKL8-38KDLALNA881
-------------------------------------------------------
companyId = 2100
-------------------------------------------------------
firstName = Jane
-------------------------------------------------------
lastName = Fonda
-------------------------------------------------------
middleInitial = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
title = Mrs.
-------------------------------------------------------
incomeCode = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
ageCode = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
structureAgeCode = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
reference = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
businessName = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
contactPhoneId = 427C367B-F490-412A-B9B0-ABABABABABAB
-------------------------------------------------------
primaryAddressId = f7668325-ba95-4bde-b28d-0226bbd4d9c7
-------------------------------------------------------
website1 = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
website2 = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
website3 = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
email1 = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
email1CanMail = false
        type = Edm.Boolean
-------------------------------------------------------
email2 = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
email2CanMail = false
        type = Edm.Boolean
-------------------------------------------------------
email3 = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
email3CanMail = false
        type = Edm.Boolean
-------------------------------------------------------
isTagged = 
        type = Edm.Boolean
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
structureValueCode = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
doNotMail = 
        type = Edm.Boolean
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
yearHomeBuilt = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
maritalStatus = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
lengthOfResidence = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
styleOfHome = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
mailMergeName = Jesse Peters
-------------------------------------------------------
source = Access - KGuard
-------------------------------------------------------
creationDate = 2015-05-15T14:49:27.06-04:00
        type = Edm.DateTime
-------------------------------------------------------
qbSyncDate = 
        type = Edm.DateTime
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
qbId = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
isActive = true
        type = Edm.Boolean
-------------------------------------------------------
lastUpdate = 2015-05-15T14:49:27.06-04:00
        type = Edm.DateTime
-------------------------------------------------------
hasDNCPhone = false
        type = Edm.Boolean
-------------------------------------------------------
hasDNEEmail = false
        type = Edm.Boolean
-------------------------------------------------------
qbEditSequence = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
qbSyncData = 
        type = Edm.Boolean
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
qbName = 
        null = true
-------------------------------------------------------
createdDate = 2015-05-15T14:49:27.06-04:00
        type = Edm.DateTime
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I need to test; I don't have access to the API generation, so I'll have to see if I can dynamically insert the NS info to the input stream. If I can, I will happily mark as answered. Do you have any alternative solutions if I can't make that work?

Comment: I don't know of another way to access namespaced tag attributes in PHP.

Comment: It's ok, I read the stream into an array, and then preg the attribute in....except I don't have to; the API has been updated to include the namespace! ;) Thanks for the help!

Comment: This answer though focused on getting all d namespace'd tags and their attributes at once (`//m:properties/d:*`). Your implementation probably needs a different approach like iterating over <entry>s and then using a direct xpath selector on each <content> node i.e. `m:properties/d:*` w/o the leading `//`.